# Thermal Operating Machine

Tags: wo2017179083a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2017179083A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017179083A1)

Inventore Errato

Il cognome corretto è "VERDE"

Comment: This is an English language forum so questions must be posted in English; however, this has already been answered on this site.

Comment: You also asked the same question in December of 2017.